# RTRIM inside LISTAGG?

Tags: sql, oracle

Good day. I am writing a query that uses LISTAGG and returns results. This is the code I have so far.

```
   select 
    listagg(rtrim(shop_cde, 1), ', ') within group (order by shop_cde) col1,
    business_cde
    from mytable
    group by business_cde
```

I expect that this returns results, aggregates them, and trims off 1 character from the right on shop_cde. However, it appears no trimming occurs. Shop_cde still shows in full. Does anyone know how to TRIM inside a LISTAGG function?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  I don't think you want `trim()` at all.

Comment: [Here you can check how to use rtrim](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rtrim.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `trim()` functions are generally used to remove leading and trailing spaces (although you can remove other characters as well).

If you want to discard the last character, use `substr()`:

```
select listagg(substr(shop_cde, 1, length(shop_cde) - 1), ', ') within group (order by shop_cde) col1,
       business_cde
from mytable
group by business_cde
```

Comment: @collapsar . . . Actually it is a little different.  I was thinking `ltrim()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `substr` if you want to remove a *given number* of charcaters from the right, use `rtrim` if you want an unspecified number of a *given character* eliminated. Removing on the left would use `substr(..., 2)` and `ltrim`, resp.

```
   select 
    listagg(substr(shop_cde, -1), ', ') within group (order by shop_cde) col1,
    business_cde
    from mytable
    group by business_cde
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use rtrim(listagg(....) )

```
select 
rtrim(listagg(shop_cde, ', ') within group (order by shop_cde) ) col1,
business_cde
from mytable
group by business_cde
```

Comment: This solution trims the synthesized list but not the underlying items.